# How to identify the independent and dependent variables in a differential equation?

Tags: calculus

I had doubt regarding the equation $y^4 = x^5$. Which one is the dependant and the independent variable here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me very much. But where do have seen the differential equation in $y^4=x^5$?

Comment: i'm sorry i meant the equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can considerate the indipendent variable the classic $x$ and dependent the $y$. I remember that

$$y^4=x^5 \iff y=\sqrt[4]{x^5}=x\sqrt[4]{x} \quad  \wedge \quad y=-\sqrt[4]{x^5}=-x\sqrt[4]{x}$$

Plotting $y=\sqrt[4]{x^5}$ you have

[image]

and plotting $y=-\sqrt[4]{x^5}$ you will have:

[image]

Hence $$y^4=x^5$$ is:

[image]

Comment: is it a convention that in an equation containing x and y, x is always the inpendent variable ?

Comment: @VenomSnake Absolutely not. Simply a convenience. You'd have to reverse the axis labels but it doesn't change the content of the answer.

Comment: Okay. Thanx a lot

Comment: @VenomSnake I am happy to help you...best regards.

Answer (score 1):

*Typically*, we use $y$ as the dependent variable, but this doesn't always have to be the case. One could interpret the above equation as
$$y(x)=x^{5/4}$$
Or as
$$x(y)=y^{4/5}$$

Can't really say much more without context.